# Encrypted Disk (LUKS): Upgrading from RHEL 8 to RHEL 9

Tags: upgrade, disk-encryption, rhel8

Known limitations - Notable known limitations of Leapp currently include:

- Encryption of the whole disk or a partition, or file-system encryption currently cannot be used on a system targeted for an in-place upgrade.

Question:

1. How do I upgrade my encrypted (LUKS) RHEL 8? This a VM on a Pop!_OS using KVM used for development.
2. The other day I install RHEL 9 using encryption (LUKS) on a physical system before knowing the above limitation. And, created two RHEL 9 VMs w/encryption (LUKS). This is my production server.
3. Will this be fixed in future upgrades or should I be using disk encryption on RHEL?

Answer (score 1):

> How do I upgrade my encrypted (LUKS) RHEL 8? This a VM on a Pop!_OS
> using KVM used for development.

Sounds like you can't.

> The other day I install RHEL 9 using encryption (LUKS) on a physical
> system before knowing the above limitation. And, created two RHEL 9
> VMs w/encryption (LUKS). This is my production server.

Oh.

> Will this be fixed in future upgrades or should I be using disk
> encryption on RHEL?

** shrugs ** No idea, ask Red Hat.

Can I suggest you read our help pages and observe the workings of this site before posting again please as I'm not sure you have done either so far.

Comment: I guest I have not, and seeing that this a place to get rude responses instead of help, I will NOT post here again!!!...

Comment: Good, it was a terrible question.

Comment: You must be getting more thrills here than with your woman if you have one or who-man!  Kiss of Troll!!!...

Comment: If you'd only put half as much effort into your question as your tantrum...

Comment: Dud, if I can get an answer from the AlmaLinux community and this place is suppose to be a "universal" place of help with the infused title of "Server", then there would be no argument of any kind by making pussy statements about reading help pages.  Either you know how to help or not, and if not keep just past on by.